# Detect if an SD card has been inserted via PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, sd-card, media, hardware-detection

I would like to use PowerShell to detect if an SD card is there. After an SD card has been detected, a PowerShell script should automatically copy some files to the SD card.

I already found and tried a PS script, but it only detects USB sticks.

```
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
write-host (get-date -format s) " Beginning script..."
do{
    $newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
    $eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType
    $eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
    {
        1 {"Configuration changed"}
        2 {"Device arrival"}
        3 {"Device removal"}
        4 {"docking"}
    }
    write-host (get-date -format s) " Event detected = " $eventTypeName
    if ($eventType -eq 2)
    {
        $driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
        $driveLabel = ([wmi]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
        write-host (get-date -format s) " Drive name = " $driveLetter
        write-host (get-date -format s) " Drive label = " $driveLabel
        # Execute process if drive matches specified condition(s)
        if ($driveLetter -eq 'E:' -and $driveLabel -eq 'Test 1')
        {
            write-host (get-date -format s) " Starting task in 3 seconds..."
            start-sleep -seconds 3
            start-process "E:test.bat"
        }
    }
    Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
} while (1-eq1) #Loop until next event
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

Comment: I have no SD card in handy so I cannot test my suggestion. But try to change `if ($eventType -eq 2)` to `if ($eventType -eq 4)`. The script then does not watch for *Device arrival* (new drive letter added?) but rather for the docking of new hardware. I also assume that you already changed `if ($driveLetter -eq 'E:' -and $driveLabel -eq 'Test 1')` to your own needs?

Comment: Hi nixda and thank you for your reply. 
I have already modified script but it still doesn't detect SD card.
The main reason (I think) why script doesn't work it is if you have an built-in SD card reader, and you eject the SD card, you are still able to find card reader under Disk Management with assigned letter.

Comment: I think you're right about the drive letter. That's why I thought Device arrival won't work. Now that I read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394124(v=vs.85).aspx) again it says *includes changes in the hardware configuration (docking and undocking)*. So docking will probably also not work. Hmmm

Answer (score 2):

When you open a USB or SD Card in Windows it logs the start of the "Virtual Disk Service" to the System Event Log in Windows.

With that in mind:

1. Insert your SD card and then open up the System log in Event Viewer.
2. At the top (or near the top) will be a "Virtual Disk Service".
3. Highlight that entry and then click on the "Details" tab below.
4. If needed, click on the plus sign next to "System".
5. Within will be the correct "EventID" for SD Cards, so use that for you script.
6. Now right click the same "Virtual Disk Service" (from step 2)
7. Select "Attach Task To This Event..."
8. Step through the "Create Basic Task Wizard" to "Action" and select "Start a program".
9. Enter the path to your PowerShell script and select Finish.